# deletion of multiple items the contextual action mode with database

Tags: android, database, android-actionbar

ı have

MainActivity.java

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, MultiChoiceModeListener {

Entry entry = null;
ListView todoListView;

ArrayList<Entry> todoItems;
ToDoArrayAdapter todoArrayAdapter;

public int itemPosition;
public long rowId;

public static final int ADD_NOTE = 1;
public static final int EDIT_NOTE = 2;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.add_note:

        Intent addIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddItem.class);
        startActivityForResult(addIntent, ADD_NOTE);

        return true;
    case R.id.lowPriority:

        return true;
    case R.id.mediumPriority:
        // refresh
        return true;
    case R.id.highPriority:
        // help action
        return true;
    case R.id.allPriority:
        // help action
        return true;
    default:
        return true;

    }
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "static-access" })
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    todoListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    // Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        todoItems = (ArrayList<Entry>) savedInstanceState
                .getSerializable("oldList");
    }

    else {
        todoItems = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    }
    todoArrayAdapter = new ToDoArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item, todoItems);
    todoListView.setAdapter(todoArrayAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);


    todoListView.setChoiceMode(todoListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

    todoListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg0) {
            todoArrayAdapter.removeSelection();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
            arg0.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, arg1);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode arg0, MenuItem arg1) {
            switch (arg1.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete:
                SparseBooleanArray selected = todoArrayAdapter.getSelectedIds();
                for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                        Entry selecteditem = todoArrayAdapter.getItem(selected
                                .keyAt(i));
                        todoArrayAdapter.remove(selecteditem);
                    }
                }
                // Close CAB
                arg0.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode arg0, int arg1, long arg2,
                boolean arg3) {
            final int checkedCount = todoListView.getCheckedItemCount();
            arg0.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
            todoArrayAdapter.toggleSelection(arg1);
        }
    });


    todoListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            rowId = todoItems.get(position).getId();

            itemPosition = position;
            Entry item_data = (Entry) todoListView
                    .getItemAtPosition(position);
            DataWrapper itemData = new DataWrapper(item_data);
            Intent editIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    EditItem.class);
            editIntent.putExtra("itemData", itemData);
            startActivityForResult(editIntent, EDIT_NOTE);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        switch (requestCode) {
        case ADD_NOTE:

            DataWrapper dw = (DataWrapper) data
                    .getSerializableExtra("addItem");

            entry = dw.getEntry();
            todoItems.add(entry);

            NewItemAdded(entry.getName(), entry.getPriorityLevel(),
                    entry.getStatus(), entry.getDay(), entry.getMonth(),
                    entry.getYear());
            todoArrayAdapter.sort(new Comparator<Entry>() {
                public int compare(Entry obj1, Entry obj2) {
                    return obj1.priorityLevel.compareTo(obj2.priorityLevel);
                }
            });

            todoArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            break;
        case EDIT_NOTE:

            int defaultValue = 0;
            defaultValue = data.getIntExtra("removeItem", defaultValue);

            if (defaultValue == 10) {

                todoItems.remove(itemPosition);
                delete_byID(rowId);

            }

            else {
                DataWrapper dw2 = (DataWrapper) data
                        .getSerializableExtra("editItem");
                entry = dw2.getEntry();
                update_byID(rowId, entry.getName(),
                        entry.getPriorityLevel(), entry.getStatus(),
                        entry.getDay(), entry.getMonth(), entry.getYear());

                todoItems.set(itemPosition, entry);
                todoArrayAdapter.sort(new Comparator<Entry>() {
                    public int compare(Entry arg0, Entry arg1) {
                        return arg0.priorityLevel
                                .compareTo(arg1.priorityLevel);
                    }
                });
            }
            todoArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("oldList", todoItems);
}

public void NewItemAdded(String task, String priority, String status,
        int day, int month, int year) {

    final ContentValues value = new ContentValues();

    value.put(ToDoContentProvider.TASK_COLUMN, task);
    String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    value.put(ToDoContentProvider.DATE_COLUMN, date);
    value.put(ToDoContentProvider.PRIORITY_COLUMN, priority);
    value.put(ToDoContentProvider.STATUS_COLUMN, status);

    final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    cr.insert(ToDoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, value);
}

public void delete_byID(long id) {
    final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    cr.delete(ToDoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,
            ToDoContentProvider.ID_COLUMN + "=" + id, null);
}

public void update_byID(long id, String task, String priority,
        String status, int day, int month, int year) {
    final ContentValues value = new ContentValues();

    value.put(ToDoContentProvider.TASK_COLUMN, task);
    String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    value.put(ToDoContentProvider.DATE_COLUMN, date);
    value.put(ToDoContentProvider.PRIORITY_COLUMN, priority);
    value.put(ToDoContentProvider.STATUS_COLUMN, status);

    final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    cr.update(ToDoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, value,
            ToDoContentProvider.ID_COLUMN + "=" + id, null);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(this, ToDoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

    todoItems.clear();

    // Gets index of the column given a name.
    final int idColumnIndex = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ToDoContentProvider.ID_COLUMN);
    final int taskColumnIndex = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ToDoContentProvider.TASK_COLUMN);
    final int dateColumnIndex = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ToDoContentProvider.DATE_COLUMN);
    final int statusColumnIndex = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ToDoContentProvider.STATUS_COLUMN);
    final int priorityColumnIndex = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ToDoContentProvider.PRIORITY_COLUMN);

    // Database queries are returned as Cursor objects.
    // Cursors are pointers to the result set within the underlying data.
    // Here is how to iterate over the cursor rows.
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) { // Moves cursor to next row, cursor is
                                    // initialized at before first.
        final String task = cursor.getString(taskColumnIndex);
        final String date = cursor.getString(dateColumnIndex);
        String s[] = date.split("/");
        int day = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(s[2]);
        final String status = cursor.getString(statusColumnIndex);
        final String priority = cursor.getString(priorityColumnIndex);
        final int id = cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex);
        todoItems.add(new Entry(id, task, priority, status, day, month,
                year));
    }

    // Notify adapter that backing data has changed.
    todoArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    todoItems.clear();
    todoArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

and

ToDoArrayAdapter.java

```
public class ToDoArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Entry> {

int resource;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;
Context context;
List<Entry> itemEntries;

public ToDoArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<Entry> itemEntries) {
    super(context, resource, itemEntries);
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.resource = resource;
    this.context = context;
    this.itemEntries = itemEntries;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView taskView;
    TextView priorityView;
    TextView statusView;
    TextView dateView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Entry entry = getItem(position);
    String task = entry.getName();
    String priority = entry.getPriorityLevel();
    String status = entry.getStatus();
    int day = entry.getDay();
    int month = entry.getMonth();
    int year = entry.getYear();

    String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

    View entryView = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (entryView == null) {
        String inflaterService = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(inflaterService);
        entryView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.taskView = (TextView) entryView.findViewById(R.id.taskView);
        holder.priorityView = (TextView) entryView
                .findViewById(R.id.priorityView);
        holder.statusView = (TextView) entryView
                .findViewById(R.id.statusView);
        holder.dateView = (TextView) entryView.findViewById(R.id.dateView);

        entryView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) entryView.getTag();
    }

    holder.taskView.setText(task);
    holder.priorityView.setText(priority);
    holder.dateView.setText(date);
    holder.statusView.setText(status);

    entryView
            .setBackgroundColor(mSelectedItemsIds.get(position) ? 0x9934B5E4
                    : Color.TRANSPARENT);

    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("DONE")) {

        holder.taskView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#145a03"));
    } else {

        if (calculateTheHourLeft(date) <= 0) {

            holder.taskView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffa500"));
        }

        else {

            holder.taskView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ea1616"));
        }

    }

    return entryView;
}

public void toggleSelection(int position) {
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
}

public void removeSelection() {
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
    if (value)
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
    else
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds;
}
```

**Error log:**

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to    instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hw2/com.example.hw2.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.hw2.MainActivity

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

12-08 17:46:14.571: E/AndroidRuntime(1955): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.hw2.MainActivity

Comment: ı cant handle this problem.What can ı do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity class is declared as abstract and therefore you cannot create an instance of it. You can only subclass it.

Remove the abstract modifier or extend the class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: when i delete abstract class,MainActivity wants unimplemented methods which are allready in todoListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener

Comment: Because you are implementing the multichoicemode interface buthave not provided methods for it. Remove the interface from the declaration if you are not using it.

Comment: i remove multichoicemode implementation program works but when i click item long, i have to select multiple and delete. how can i do this?

Comment: You need to ask another question as your original one has been answered and your new one is unrelated. Don't forget to mark this question as answered.